# Call is interrupted after 60 seconds in network tab

Tags: networking, browser, timeout, call, seconds

I was trying to run a script that downloads a file and I found out that when execution time exceeds 60 seconds the operation is interrupted.
Here is the network tab of my browser :

pic1:[image]

pic2:[image]

How can I increase that value? I think it is related to a server timeout but I can find out which one.

Comment: you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919706/why-is-the-initial-connection-time-for-a-http-request-so-long

Comment: I think it's not the same case