# One request is slow one is fast

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a "/categories/list" api. I used memory cache for that api. When i trigger it from postman, it always returning between 4 ms and 12 ms. But when i test it from my react app. One response is 7 ms and second response is over 300 ms. I also test it from Microsoft Edge, it is same. Why it is getting over 300ms?

```
axios.get("/api/1.0/categories/list");
```

[image: browser developer tools]

**Update:**

I noticed a new situation. There is no problem for server response time. It looks about initial connection. Why might this be happening?

[image: ss]

Comment: The fast ones are preflight requests (`OPTIONS` method). This checks if the resource is available. Afterwards the actual request (`GET` method) is performed.

Comment: how about your api server? try measuring the processing time in your backend.

Comment: While we may be able to speculate on why some calls to your undescribed API seem to take longer than others, without more information how can we provide a correct answer? It looks like some calls are cached and some are not.

Comment: In server side, it's getting under 5 ms for every request. Also i checked it with logs. Cache is working without problem. @irous

Comment: In server side, it's getting under 5 ms for every request. Also i checked it with logs. Cache is working without problem. @Jodrell

Comment: What else is the browser doing?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check again. @Jodrell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919706/why-is-the-initial-connection-time-for-a-http-request-so-long

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/784591/ssl-initial-connection-painfully-slow-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the browser, you make 2 requests, unlike Postman. One is OPTIONS for check CORS and one is GET, POST, etc. Your API server returns a header when OPTIONS request which is Access-Control-Max-Age. Access-Control-Max-Age value stands for how long wait for the next OPTIONS request. May your API was not set an Access-Control-Max-Age header or set for too short therefore your browser always makes 2 requests. Needs to be more investigation here to be sure. Furthermore, axios is a package and it needs time to execute whatever it is intended to do. And if you want to go a little more deeper ---> axios requests are handled by Microtask Queue which has facade functions with libUV library of browser and it takes some time to register such events etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue.
I'm not sure what causes it but I have found a workaround:

Navigate to 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of localhost:3000

All consecutive requests now have 0 initial connection time, for me at least.